# Finder won't remember window size in Yosemite

Tags: finder, macos

In previous versions there was a way to set the window configuration as default. But now in Yosemite they seem to have got rid of this option.

There is however a way to make it remember for a while with `option + drag` a new (untouched) finder window. But this won't last long. After a while or a restart the window is back to stock settings.

Is this a bug? Because I can't recall experiencing this in previous versions of OS X. If not, is there a way to set a default window configuration?

Comment: Having this same issue... I tried setting Finder windows to the way I want them and then locking the .DS_Store files. I tried removing every .DS_Store file on the file system. It seems like the Finder is just ignoring settings... Very odd and random. Wish I had something more useful to contribute.

Comment: For what it's worth, my Finder windows have never remembered their size, long before Yosemite...

Comment: Performing a full system cleanup with Onyx. Also removing Finder preferences from the Library might help too.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know any way to change the default window size, but you can use a script like this to reset the properties of windows manually:

```
tell application "Finder"
    if number of Finder windows is 0 then return
    tell Finder window 1
        set toolbar visible to false
        set sidebar width to 0
        set statusbar visible to false
        set current view to column view
        set bounds to {960, 22, 1920, 1076}
        tell its column view options
            set shows icon to false
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```